# How for each works while passing two array variables in varargs argument?

Tags: java

While running this code i am getting an output 14.But i am unable to understand that how for each loop works on two array variables passing in single varargs argument.

```
public class Venus 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int [] x = {1,2,3};
        int y[] = {4,5,6};
        new Venus().go(x,y);
    }

    void go(int[]... z) 
    {
        for(int[] a : z)
        System.out.print(a[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int[]...` translates to `int[][]`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ellipsis means "accept any number of arguments and give them to me in an array"

So

```
void go(int[]... x)
```

accepts multiple `int[]` arguments and puts them in an array of `int[]`, which means that the result is `int[][]`.

When you iterate through an `int[][]`, each element is of type `int[]`, an array of `int`.